# formating strings from a list after joining them

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list full of both strings and integers.

```py
orderedlist = ['hp10', 2, 'dex4', 1, 'init1', 2, 'ac1', 1, 'damage2', 2, 'hit3', 2, 'init3', 2, 'hit4', 2, 'hp20', 2, 'damage1', 2, 'hit2', 1, 'damage5', 1]
```

I want to arrange it such that the output looks like this:

```
hp10: 2, dex4: 1: init1: 2, ac1: 1, damage2: 2, hit3: 2, init3: 2, hit4: 2, hp20: 2, damage1: 2, hit2: 1, damage5: 1
```

I have written code such that I can obtain this partially, but am unable to put in the commas. The code I have:

```py
string = map(str, orderedlist)
shopList = ": ".join(string)
print(shopList)
```

Of course, this outputs:

```
hp10: 2: dex4: 1: init1: 2: ac1: 1: damage2: 2: hit3: 2: init3: 2: hit4: 2: hp20: 2: damage1: 2: hit2: 1: damage5: 1
```

How can I get the commas in place of the colons, after the amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` with list slicing

**Ex:**

```
orderedlist = ['hp10', 2, 'dex4', 1, 'init1', 2, 'ac1', 1, 'damage2', 2, 'hit3', 2, 'init3', 2, 'hit4', 2, 'hp20', 2, 'damage1', 2, 'hit2', 1, 'damage5', 1]

print(", ".join("{}: {}".format(*i) for i in zip(orderedlist[::2], orderedlist[1::2])))
```

**Output:**

```
hp10: 2, dex4: 1, init1: 2, ac1: 1, damage2: 2, hit3: 2, init3: 2, hit4: 2, hp20: 2, damage1: 2, hit2: 1, damage5: 1
```